# How to show $kerT^t=(im T)^0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this is just putting together the definitions, but I am unsure if I should be making a rank argument or looking at the elements in each set.

Comment: What do you mean by $(imT)^0$?

Comment: It's likely the annihilator, i.e., $\operatorname{im} T^\perp$.

Comment: You should be able to prove it using only the definitions of kernel and annihilator, perhaps also $Av=v^TA^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Denotes $\langle u,v\rangle=v^tu\ $ so that $\langle Av,u \rangle = u^{t}Av$ where $u,v$ have the appropriate size. It's not hard to see that, for matrix with real entries, we have $\langle Av,u \rangle = \langle v,A^{t}u \rangle$.

Therefore $v\in ker(A)\iff\forall u\,\,\langle Av,u \rangle = \langle 0,u \rangle =0 \iff \forall u\,\,\langle v,A^{t}u \rangle=0 \iff v\perp w\,\,\forall w\in Im(A^{t}) \iff v\in Im(A^{t})^{\perp}$

Thus $ker(A)=Im(A^{t})^{\perp}$.